# How to get the current time of the operating system of a computer in the LAN using its IP address?

Tags: java

If we have a local network, I'd like to get the current time of the operating system of a specific computer in the network:
assume that my java program is located on a computer: 192.168.10.100
and I want to know the current time of the OS in another computer: 192.168.10.101

My solution:

I can prepare simple TCP client-server java programs, so the server program will be listening on 192.168.10.101 and will reply the requests coming from the client program which is located on 192.168.10.100 with the OS time.

My question:

Is there any simpler solution which needs only one program to get the time of OS of a specific computer in LAN, without establishing a connection between two programs in the requester and destination computers!

Comment: it would help to mention what operating systems are the machines running on

Comment: @Shekhar in my case both are Windows 7

Comment: Have you considered using [NTP](http://www.linux.org/threads/tcp-ip-protocol-network-time-protocol-ntp.4912) or [SNTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SNTP)?

Comment: In UNIX-like OS, there is a built-in daytime server(not enabled by default). So, u can get the time using just a client program. [See this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daytime_Protocol#Inetd_implementation) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [`net time`](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_time.mspx?mfr=true) shell command.

Comment: Try to avoid link only answers, links die and then the answer become useless.

Comment: @Shekhar this answer, while not thorough, would still provide information without the link so, it isn't a link-only answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any simpler solution which needs only one program to get the time of OS of a specific computer in LAN, without establishing a connection between two programs in the requester and destination computers!

How? How can one computer *possibly* know the state of another computer without connecting to it? Computers are not psychic.

No, the computer must connect to the other computer in order to get information from it, such as the current time.

So you're going to have to write a java program that connects to the other computer on the LAN.

Now, if your question is can you avoid writing a second program, maybe. You can try to get access to the shell of the machine you're connecting to from your java program, but you're going to have to implement SSH in your java program, which isn't going to be easy. You could find an SSH library perhaps, although Windows 7 doesn't support SSH anyways.

Easiest by far would be to simply write two programs, or write a single program that can act as sever or client. Then run it on both computers, have one computer connect to the other, and then they can communicate back and forth about what time each computer's OS has. Since you're writing the program yourself you can make the rules about the protocol and determine which port it will listen on, and you can guarantee that the program will be running and listening on that port.